# Apache Airflow logic on executing next BashOperator task

Tags: python, bash, automation, airflow

I'm fairly new to airflow and I was wondering how can I add some logic to my dag.

If that is the place for that at least, or do I need to create a operator for logic ?

Here is my dag:

with DAG(dag_id='test_dag', schedule_interval=None, catchup=False, default_args=default_args) as dag:

```
start: DummyOperator = DummyOperator(task_id='start')

task_one = BashOperator(
    task_id='tsk_1',
    xcom_push=True,
    provide_context=True,
    bash_command=BASH_CMD)

task_two = BashOperator(
    task_id='tsk_2',
    xcom_push=True,
    provide_context=True,
    bash_command=BASH_CMD)

end: DummyOperator = DummyOperator(task_id='end')

start >> task_one >> task_two >> end
```

At the end of my statement I am using ";echo $?" and when I check xcom I get proper variable saved as "return_value": 0 - that is fine/

I was trying to do some logic like I want to handle that error in some way, for instance if return code is 0 then I want to execute task_2, how can I achieve this?

I know I have to use xcom_pull to dig that variable and what puzzles me if this is the place to do it, in a dag?

And if you guys can point me in right direction, I only need hints, maybe even some kind of examples to try and understand how and where my logic needs to be.

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is the concept of **branching** in Airflow.

`BranchPythonOperator` is your main operator to achieve this. all you need to start using this operator is to return the target task ID according to XCom or any other sources.
check out [this great post](https://marclamberti.com/blog/airflow-branchpythonoperator/).